# Run ruby script in docker with installed gems

Tags: ruby, docker

What would be a quick way to run a ruby script that needs a few gems within a docker container?

I often come across the situation where I want to try out a new gem, or write a short script, and I don't want to install the gem locally. My first idea was to write a `Dockerfile` and build the image, e.g.

```
FROM ruby:latest

RUN gem install httparty
COPY test.rb /usr/app/

CMD ["ruby", "/usr/app/test.rb"]
```

and `test.rb`

```
require "httparty"
puts HTTParty.get("https://now.httpbin.org/").body
```

Then run `docker build -t run-ruby-with-gems .` and after the build `docker run -it --rm run-ruby-with-gems`

This works, but isn't handy. So maybe there is some smart one liner or anything else that could make the whole process of quickly running a ruby script easier.

Comment: Create a new gemset, install the new gem into it, test it, and remove a gemset looks not as fashionable and hypey as using docker, but works like a charm :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to use `docker-compose` for that task.
See this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ruby:
    image: ruby:latest
    command: bash -c 'gem install httparty && ruby test.rb'
    working_dir: /usr/app/
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/app/
```

Place docker-compose.yml file in same directory with test.rb and then run command: `docker-compose up` everytime when you want to test your changes - in gems and in code.

This docker-compose configuration run command with installing gems and running your application with every `up`. You don't need to rebuild anything because using volume mapping you have 'hot replace' of your code directly into container.